# В чём разница между «import java.util.*» и «import java.util.Scanner»

Tags: java, импорт

Вместо `Scanner` может быть что угодно - суть ясна. А именно: зачем использовать второй вариант, если первый и набирать короче, и пригодится когда понадобится что-то ещё из `java.util`? Изучаю Java и во многих примерах из книг и статьях в интернете используется второй вариант импорта, но нигде не видел объяснения почему именно так. Наверное, у него есть какие-то преимущества перед первым?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что в Java импорты нужны для разделения классов. Понятнее будет на примере. Допустим есть класс `com.blabla.Scanner` и вы написали `import com.blabla.*;`. А потом вам захотелось добавить импорт от `java.util.Scanner` и вы опять написали `import java.util.*;`. В этом случае, если вы в коде напишете `Scanner`, компилятор не поймет какой именно `Scanner` вам нужен. Полная запись импорта это не допустит

Помню, как-то добавил импорт от `android.support.v7.widget.*` и `android.widget.*;`. Когда я написал `Toolbar` IDE как раз и заругалась, так как он есть в обоих пакетах. Добавил к `v7.widget.Toolbar` и все.

Comment: Исчерпывающе. Спасибо.

Comment: @Эмий Октофополус, не за что! Кстати, я недавно начал писать полные импорты всегда, уж очень много одинаковых имен классов в библиотеках)

Answer (score 9):

Аргументы за и против обоих вариантов есть в ответах к [этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad). Там же, в комментариях к ответам, сплошной холивар по поводу того, что "это не повод так делать, а делать наоборот - повод есть".

Выделить оттуда можно такие моменты.

За импорт всего пакета:

- Не приходится писать огромное количество импортов, а читающему - их пролистывать
- В плане производительность разницы нет
- Конфликты имён встречаются не часто и довольно просто разрешаются
- "Так советуют делать в книгах". В качества примера [приводится отрывок](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992695/3432401) из книги "Clean Code" Robert C. Martin. За достоверность отрывка не ручаюсь.

За перечисление конкретных классов:

- Не происходят конфликты имён при импорте класса только из одного пакета. Причём речь идёт не только про первоначальную разработку кода, но и про переход на более новую версию Java. Коронным примером является переход с JDK 1.1 на 1.2 и `import java.util.*;` с `import java.awt.*;` при использовании `List`.
- Возможность понять к какому пакету относится класса при чтении кода без IDE
- Если в классе много импортов, то, вероятно, этот класс делает [больше, чем должен](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)
- В современных IDE можно скрыть блок импортов, чтобы не приходилось их пролистывать

В итоге всё сводится к тому, что каждый решает для себя сам какой подход ему использовать. Лучшего решения нет, о чём, в том числе, свидетельствует бесконечный спор на эту тему.

Comment: В общем, насколько я понял, пишу звёздочки и не парюсь, пока не возникнет ну прям острая необходимость, как у @Flippy.

Comment: @ЗмийОктофополус всё сводится к тому, что каждый решает для себя сам. Лучшего решения нет, о чём свидетельствует бесконечный спор на эту тему.

Comment: @ЗмийОктофополус делать надо так как вы договоритесь в команде. если вы пишите один, то можете делать как угодно.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.* - импортируешь все, что есть в библиотеке
import java.util.Scanner - импортируешь конкретно Scanner